# SQL Server detect one to one or one to many

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I need to detect whether the foreign key is 1-1 or 1-many. How can I do this in SQL Server ?

My use case is I'm expanding PetaPoco so that it has additional computed fields which points to the corresponding foreign key record. The problem is I have tables with both 1-1 and 1-many. I need to detect so that the additional field can either be a poco or List.

```
    SELECT tab1.name as [source_table],
col1.name AS [source_column],
 tab2.name AS [referenced_table],
    col2.name AS [referenced_column]
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
    ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
    ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
    ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
```

Comment: I don't think you have a reliable way unless there is a unique constraint on the foreign key.

Comment: Or the foreign key is also the primary key or unique index.